# Add background image to Google Fusion Tables map info window?

Tags: css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables, infowindow

I'm creating a custom info window layout for a Google Fusion Tables map. One of my columns specifies the (partial) image name, which is then used as a background image. I'd like this background image to be flush with the edge of the info window. The code I've written below works in native html, but not in the info window because:

1. The background image doesn't show (it defaults to the flat colour behind)
2. I can't get rid of the padding around my content within the info window

> ```
> <div class='googft-info-window' style='font-family: sans-serif; width:495px; padding:0px; margin:0px;'>
> <div style="width:495px; height:36px; background:url(http://www.exampleurl.com/images/{header_hex}.gif) #{header_hex};">
> <a href="{url}" style="font-weight:bold;font-size:14pt;color:#0066ff; text-decoration:none;" target="_blank" >{item}</a>
> </div>
> </div>
> ```

Any ideas gratefully received... Thanks.

EDITED TO ADD:

I'm also having problems embedding a video into my info window. There's only one video - on the yellow marker to the east on the map link below. (There's a broken image showing in this marker's info window just above where the video ought to be because the image hasn't been uploaded yet). The video embed code I'm using is:

```
<iframe width="300" height="165" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/-yYLLb53V8E?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I'm using Fusion Tables (experimental) and my info window layout is:

```
<div class='googft-info-window' style='font-family:sans-serif; color:#666; width:495px; padding:0px; margin:0px;'>

<div style="width:495px; background:url(http://www.responsibletravel.com/imagesclient/{header_hex}.gif) #{header_hex};"><div style="padding:8px;">
<a href="{url}" style="font-weight:bold;font-size:14pt;color:#0066ff; text-decoration:none;" target="_blank" >{item}</a>
</div></div>

<div style="float:left; width:330px; padding-top:10px;">
<div style="width:330px; padding-bottom:15px;">{description}</div>
<div style="width:330px; padding-bottom:15px;"><a href="{url}" style="color:#0066ff; text-decoration:none;" target="_blank" >Read more about this {type}</a></div>
<div style="width:330px;">{enquiry_url}</div>
<div style="width:330px;"><a href="{review_url}" target="_blank" >{stars}</a> <a href="{review_url}" style="color:#0066ff; text-decoration:none;" target="_blank" >{reviews}</a></div>
<div style="float:left; width:110px; padding-top:10px">
<span style="font-weight:bold; font-size:11px">Share this:</span><br>
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u={url}&t={item}" style="color:#0066ff; text-decoration:none;" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.responsibletravel.com/imagesclient/facebook-button-26.gif" style="border:0; padding:5px 5px 5px 0px;"></a>
<a href="http://twitter.com/home?status={item}+{url}+%28via+%40r_travel%29" style="color:#0066ff; text-decoration:none;" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.responsibletravel.com/imagesclient/twitter-button-26.gif" style="border:0; padding:5px 5px 5px 0px;"></a>
</div>
<div style="float:left; width:100px; padding-top:26px">{xsell_icon_1}</div>
</div>

<div style="float:right; width:160px; padding-top:10px;">
<div style="float:right; padding-top:10px"><a href="{url}" target="_blank" ><img src='{image_S}' width='148' style='float:right; vertical-align:top; border:0'alt="{item}"/></a></div>
<div style="float:right; padding-top:5px">{video_embed}</div>
<div style="float:right; padding-top:10px"><a href="http://www.visitbrighton.com" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.responsibletravel.com/imagesclient/visit-brighton-logo-148x58.gif" style="border:0; width:148px;"></a></div>
</div>

</div>
```

The map is here (some of the info is still being populated but you get the idea):

https://www.google.com/fusiontables/embedviz?viz=MAP&q=select+col0+from+1r9PzOl93v_3amDCSXBHJcWhMCK6X9BufzF4TJhM&h=false&lat=50.82791056751128&lng=-0.14479637145996094&z=15&t=1&l=col0&y=1&tmplt=1

Thank you...

Comment: can you put up a sample on a jsfiddle or provide a link to the current problem, i may have a solution for you if the problem you're experiencing is what i think it is

Comment: @suvi Thanks - I'll have a link I can share tomorrow. I also can't embed a youtube video in my info window, which seems odd given that it's owned by Google...

Comment: that's strange, I can embed videos in infoWindows when testing it out..how are you embedding it? are you using the iframe embed code youtube gives? it should work if you are

Comment: @suvi I've added some info to my original post, if you wouldn't mind taking a look? Thank you.

Comment: Ok so did a little inspecting and found the problem to your first concern. If you see the resulting portion of your html for one of your infoWindows `<div style="width:495px;background:url('') #c6b5eb">` you can see that the background image url is not being loaded in. Your `{header_hex}` value is being pulled in properly, but the problem is that the resulting url: `http://www.responsibletravel.com/imagesclient/c6b5eb.gif` does not actually exist. Let me know if the problem persists after you've switched up the proper directories/paths.

Comment: regarding the youtube video though, how are you actually storing it in your `{video_embed}`? because when I put the `<iframe width="300" height="165" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/-yYLLb53V8E?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>` code in the div on chrome dev tools, it shows up fine.

Comment: Hi @suvi Thanks for looking into this for me. Apologies for the confusion - I had to make some changes to compensate for the background image not working which meant the image url it was creating by the time you saw it wasn't correct. However, even when I put the correct image url directly into the custom info window layout template (without referencing the table) it doesn't show up. Ditto for the video - I added exactly that code above into the template but it's just ignored. Could this be because I'm using experiemntal vs classic or kml? Thanks...

Comment: Hmm, I won't be able to answer that for you as I'm not too sure about it myself. But allow me add a couple more tags to this question, you may find someone that has the answer you're looking for.